# Need info on ldap for trial

Tags: ldap

I want to try using ldap in my home laptop.I want this to test authentication for SOAP Webservices.
I am not sure which link provides the ldap installation steps.and what is the trial software i can use for ldap.
Could someone please suggest me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at the http://forgerock.com/products/open-identity-stack/opendj/ product for an easy and free (for testing) purposes install.